# Reflect pset4 CS50

Tags: c, cs50

Hi to everyone who did CS50,

Currently, I am doing pset4 filter, reflect and struggling with the code I wrote. It compiles fine, but the output picture looks like the one that I attached. Has any a clue for me how I could fix this? (If possible without the solution; a hint is totally fine :))

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < (height - 1); i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < (width - 1); j++)
       {
           //get the average
           float average = 0;
           average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3;

           //set color channels with the average value
           image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(average);
           image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(average);
           image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(average);
       }
   }
   return;
}

// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < (height - 1); i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < (width - 1); j++)
       {
           //calculate the new values
           float red = 0;
           float green = 0;
           float blue = 0;


           red = .393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
           if (round(red) > 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
           }
           else if (round(red <= 255))
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
           }

           green = .349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
           if (round(green) > 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
           }
           else if (round(green) <= 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
           }

           blue = .272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + .534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + .131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
           if (round(blue) > 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
           }
           else if (round(blue) <= 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
           }
       }
   }
   return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < (height - 1); i++)
   {
       //RGBTRIPLE

       int a[width - 1 /2];
       int b[width - 1 /2];
       int c[width - 1 /2];

       for (int j = 0; j < ((width/2) - 1); j++)
       {
           a[j] = image[i][(width - 1) - j].rgbtRed;
           b[j] = image[i][(width - 1) - j].rgbtGreen;
           c[j] = image[i][(width - 1) - j].rgbtBlue;
       }

       // GERADE / UNGERADE ZAHLEN VERARBEITEN

       for (int n = 0; (n + (width - 1) /2) < (width - 1); n++)
       {
           image[i][((width - 1)/2) - n].rgbtRed = image[i][((width - 1)/2) - n].rgbtRed;
           image[i][((width - 1)/2) - n].rgbtGreen = image[i][((width - 1)/2) - n].rgbtGreen;
           image[i][((width - 1)/2) - n].rgbtBlue = image[i][((width - 1)/2) - n].rgbtBlue;
       }

       for (int m = 0; m < ((width/2) - 1); m++)
       {
           image[i][m].rgbtRed = a[m];
           image[i][m].rgbtRed = b[m];
           image[i][m].rgbtRed = c[m];
       }
   }
   return;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
   return;
}
```

Input:

```
./filter -r stadium.bmp outfile.bmp
```

(stadium.bmp is just a file that I choose. You can choose any file as the input)

Output: compiles successfully, please see attached picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wg5K.png)

Comment: So you successfully wrote a program which creates a cool-looking picture. I do not get what you specific programming related question is.

Comment: haha thanks. The main intension to reflect the picture vertically. However, the output is not reflected as you can see. Instead, I get this output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complicated. You do not need to divide image into RGB values. You need to **swap** the image values from left to right or vice versa to achieve reflection.

For this you may need to create a temporary data structure which is the same as "image".

```
RGBTRIPLE temp[width];
```

With `temp`, you need to store values from `image`, and swap them. Following is a design pattern which you can use.

```
//Pseudo code
1. //Loop though the row of an image (start from row = 0). We need to iterate every row.
    2. // Loop through the height of an image to save current row in an image to the temp.
    3. // Swap the values in image by using the temp.
```

If you want to filter this one dimensional image below.

```
val1, val2, valn, val3, val4
```

After reflection filter, it will be like this.

```
val4, val3, valn, val2, val1
```

Comment: thanks! I understood everything until the swapping part in your pseudocode. Could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: I understood it like that for the swapping part: 1. loop through each row 2. meanwhile store each image value in temp ( temp[j] = image[height][width];) 3. make another loop trough the height and then iterate through the rows again, however this time from right to left (for (int j = 0; width - 1 - j < 0; j++)).

Comment: Hi Nisanth, your 2nd comment is exactly what you need to do! I improved my answer with an example.

Comment: I did implement it. The picture is getting reflected, however I do have black vertical line in the middle of the picture. Also the first row and the last column seem to have been changed. Do you know where the mistake lies?

Comment: That's good! One step at a time. Actually if the number of elements in the row is even, then you need to consider what will happen to the middle element. The middle elements will have to remain without a change! Because they are at the center and there is no mirror image at the mirror point! :)

If the first row and last column is not right, then check your loop conditions carefully. You probably doing something wrong there. But it should not be difficult to fix!

Comment: I fixed it thanks. I used ceil and floor to tackle the the problem. I would like to show you my current code. I am new to SO and I am not certain of all the common rules here. What would be the best to upload and show you the code? It does what I but it fails the testing